# How to bind data to Data-grid-view using List with extended objects

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I try to bind `List<Member>` to DataGrid but I have no idea how to do it.
I have two classes:

```
public class Member
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double salary { get; set; }
}

public class Player : Member
{
    public double bonus { get; set; }
}
```

`List<Member>` contains both `Member` and `Player` objects. I know I should cast a `Member` object to a `Player` where it is needed. I do not know how to do it within one list.

If I bind `List <Member>`, it only displays `Member` variables and their values without additional fields if the object is, in fact, a `Player`. Should I iterate it and how?

This is how I collect them now:

```
List<Member> list = db.Members.ToList();
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Return is:

```
Member
Player
```

[image: Output]

Expectation:

[image: Expect]

Comment: What's `Senior` is it a class or instance?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong, I've already edited the post. In fact, as a `Senior` I meant `Player`

Comment: If you only want to use `Member` properties value the `List<Member>` should be enough

Comment: I need to use `Member` properties value for `Members` and `Player` properties value for `Player `, I cannot cast it because it throw exception it is `List<Member>`. Looking for way to bind it to table

Comment: So did you mean you have two tables one is for `Members` , another is for `Player`? I think you need to use two list instead of one

Comment: I add my expectations to post as image. Ok, so if i take two lists can I add them to Datagrid together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give one type if you use `List` collection, so you can try to let `List<Member>`  convert to `List<Player>`

from your expect result `bonus` property can be `double?`

```
public class Member
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double salary { get; set; }
}

public class Player : Member
{
    public double? bonus { get; set; }
}
```

**Binding** on the girdview by `Player` list.

```
List<Player> list = db.Members.Select(x => {
Player p = x as Player;

    if (p != null)
        return p;

    return new Player()
    {
        id = x.id,
        name = x.name,
        salary = x.salary
    };
});
dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution works perfekt. Just need to add `.ToList() ` method

Answer (score 1):

Unless you add the columns explicitly (eg. in designer), the columns are auto-created from the element type of the bound list. As this is `Member` in your example the grid will have no `Salary` column. So maybe you can create a list of some transformed class created like this:

```
public class MemberViewModel
{
    private Member member;
    public MemberViewModel(Member member) => this.member = member;

    public int Id => member.id;
    public string Name => member.name;
    public double Salary => member.salary;
    public double? Bonus => member is Player player ? player.bonus : default(double?);
}
```

And then:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = myOriginalMemberList.Select(member => new MemberViewModel(member)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, for explain. A bit longer but also work perfekt. Will be halpfull in future

Answer (score 0):

You must retrieve data from `Player` instead of `Member`

```
List<Player> list = db.Players.ToList();
```

Comment: I tried in this way, but only returns `Players`,but I need `Member` and `Player` in one table together. Is there any chance to marge it?

Comment: That is already sloved by other friend. There is only one table `Member`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast your `Member` to a `Player` and if it is a success then you can add that value to the grid:

```
foreach(var record in list)
{
    var player = record as Player; // try to cast your record to Player
    if (player != null)
    {
        // if it is a player do something with it
        ...
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will give you the idea how you can manage to case and add Players to the grid.

Comment: I know I can cast those objects but I don't know how to bind them together to one datagrid